# SimpleXml problems accessing xml nodes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i have serious problems accessing nodes of a specific xml file:

http://write.fm/cqsmrf5

with print_r i get the following result:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [RecordSet] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [dataSource] => testdatabase
                    [totalRecordCount] => 3573
                )

            [Record] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [counter] => 1
                                )

                            [Fields] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Field] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Barcelona
                                            [1] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [counter] => 2
                                )

                            [Fields] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Field] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => CÃ¡diz
                                            [1] => 2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

I tried to access through the command 
print `$xml->recordset->record[0]->fields->field[0];`
But i only get the error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.php on line 18
```

Could anyone help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XML is case-sensitive](http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_syntax.asp). Try

```
$xml->RecordSet->Record[0]->Fields->Field[0]; // Barcelona
```

Comment: Thanks,
i'm pretty new to this stuff. Sorry for my trivial question :-)